# Why save validator code in a variable

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm doing the following [tutorial](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/validation/) but don't really grasp why I need to save the validator code in a variable. 
Is it because I'm referencing it later with the validator.showErrors?

Can't I just use the event argument from submitHandler?

Here is the code.

```
Template.login.onRendered(function ( ){
    var validator = $(".login").validate({
        submitHandler: function (event) {
            var email = $("[name=email]").val();
            var password = $("[name=password]").val();
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    if (error.reason == "User not found") {
                        validator.showErrors({
                            email: "That email doesn't belong to a registered user."
                        });
                    }
                    if (error.reason == "Incorrect password") {
                        validator.showErrors({
                            password: "You entered an incorrect password"
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    var currentRoute = Router.current().route.getName();
                    if (currentRoute == "login") {
                        Router.go("home");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, it's because you're referencing `validator.showErrors` in the callback from `Meteor.loginWithPassword`. Some of this is just the way the jQuery validation plug-in works. [aldeed:autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform) has a completely different validation pattern for example.